# How should I tell my professor that I want to quit internship that I am doing under him?

Tags: job, interpersonal-issues

**A little background about me**: I am an undergraduate engineering student currently doing my internship remotely at a prestigious foreign university since January. I have been working there for almost 6 months now. The execution of the project is very poor. No explanation of the prior work and what is to be done. No support if faced any problem. Although the project is good and in the due course of this time I've learnt a lot in it, it's not the project is not something I am very passionate about. The work seems monotonous to me and I often end up helpless and start feeling depressed. I am all alone in my internship with no team and do have a weekly call with my professor. My professor is a very nice and knowledgeable person but has very high expectations. He asks me to do stuff that experienced researchers in that field are doing and forgets I am a junior year undergraduate student. All he does is ask me to do work that I had never done before, no proper internet resource available and expects me to present the results within the week itself. He hardly listens to me except for what I say about the task I did that week and very often scolds me.

**Present**: I have officially completed the internship as prescribed by the international student relation office of both my university and his university and have completed the targets. But my professor now wants to keep me working informally under him. Keeping in mind, I don't even get a stipend of any kind. Now I am about to start an internship in a firm within a week that I am very passionate to work with. But working there would consume a lot of my weekdays time thus leaving me no room for continuing my present internship under the professor. I want to convey to my professor that I won't be able to work under after 10 or so days. Although I wasn't fully satisfied with my internship I want to end it on a good note and a positive relationship with him.

I am so scared and confused as to how to inform him about my situation. Any ideas as to what I should be mentioning to keep my tone humble and polite and convey my desire to leave the internship?

Kind regards
-Ravi

Comment: "Dear Prof X,
I have enjoyed working on our research over the past few months and learnt many useful skills. I have another internship opportunity for the summer that I would like to pursue. Since our targets have been met and the internship is officially complete, I would like to move on to my next opportunity. 
Thank you."
Would this not work? I find that a direct approach is better with profs in Western universites. There is a far less likelihood that you'll have to walk on eggshells so as to not offend them. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @justauser thanks a lot. I am pretty scared that he might ask me to work informally under him thus might force me to do the current internship alongside my new one. The amount of work he gives just stresses me out and the lack of support I get is why I decided to quit it. Should I be saying to him directly that I've found a better opportunity, somewhere I am more passionate about and won't be able to work with him under any circumstance? And is it better to write him this in an email or tell him in our next video corenference with him?

Comment: If you did get a stipend would you be interested? Would the new internship make helping impossible? Do you fear retaliation from a "nice" professor? Can you make them happy with little effort? I wonder if there are cultural aspects that make an answer impossible for someone outside India.

Comment: @Ravi I would not use phrases like 'better opportunity' or 'more passionate about'. Instead, just say that you have a 'new opportunity' and while you enjoyed your project with the prof, it's not possible to manage time between both projects. I think conveying this face to face is better. Be direct, but polite.